# Как добавить русские символы в бд?

Tags: python, sqlite3, django

У меня не получается добавить русские слова в бд. К примеру есть такая модель:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)

#добавление в бд
s = 'Привет мир'
us = s.decode('utf-8')
a = Author.objects.create(name = us) # нормально добавляет
Book.objects.create(name = a) # здесь Bad Unicode data
```

Как правильно добавить данные в бд? Я похоже, чего то простого не понимаю.

Comment: Спасибо всем, извините меня за мою тупость, не правильно пример привел, в нем все нормально будет добавляться, ошибка была в __unicode__, вопрос решен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В первом случае в таблицу с авторами добавляете строку "а", а во втором случае при работе с книгами вместо строки работаете с объектом базы данных.
p.s. попробуйте добавить вместо этой пародии тупо через админку, там хотя бы напишет, какие ошибки, а не просто не удаётся добавить.

Answer (score 1):

Прежде всего в файле, в котором Вы используете русские символы, укажите системе, что кодировка по умолчанию UTF-8.
Это делается при помощи строки:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

в первой строке файла. Дальше можете использовать русские символы без декодирования/кодирования. Не забывайте, что БД или таблица, в которую вы пишите, тоже должна иметь базовую кодировку utf8_unicode.

В консоли всё проще. Скажите строке, что она Юникодная:

```
s = u'Привет мир'
```

Строка us = s.decode('utf-8') в этом случаи более  не нужна.

А для вставки записи в БД вы забыли вызвать save():

```
a.save()
```

Comment: Спасибо, я это знаю и проблема все еще есть.